# How to merge branches and specific 'bugfix' changesets across branches?

Tags: mercurial, branch

I am fairly new to mercurial and version control in general. I am using bitbucket and TortoiseHg. I wanted to manage my project with one stable and one dev branch. Making a branch named 'dev' was easy. Now I am about to finish current iteration and hence want to merge the dev branch into the 'default' branch. I have tried searching but to no avail.

Also I would like to confirm it again. Merging my dev branch into stable means my stable code will be replaced with the newer dev code, right? Also what should I do? Should I make a completely diffrent repo for dev or branch it in the same repo? A different repo means I can fix bugs in one and 'push' it into the other. But can the same be done with branches? if yes then how?

Comment: _"Merging my dev branch into stable means my stable code will be replaced with the newer dev code.. right?"_ `Replaced` - no. `Combined with` - **yes.**

Comment: hmm yes but there will be a ton of conflicts. how do you suggest i solve them all? a force merge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `stable` and `dev` are [named branches](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/NamedBranches) in the same repository, then to merge `dev` into `stable`, you switch to `stable` and do a merge:

```
$ hg up stable
$ hg merge dev
```

You might want to check out the docs for `hg resolve` in case there are merge conflicts that can't be resolved.

---

About moving a specific changeset to another branch you might want to check out [`hg transplant`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TransplantExtension)

Comment: well thanks for the answer.. i am still a little confused. my dev branch changes a ton of code and there were be a ton of conflicts. i would simply want to do a 'fore merge' is that a good thing? also which one will be forced? how do i make sure that stable code is the one that is replaced and not the dev code?

Comment: `hg resolve` ... if you are in the `stable` branch (you did `hg up stable`), then when you merge `dev` it will merge from `dev -> stable`

Comment: from what i understand from the docs, in `hg resolve` i will resolve the conflicts line by line. But in my case i just want to do a force merge. I dont need anything from he stable branch anymore. so can i `-f` force merge all my dev code to the stable so that it overwrites the stable code?

Comment: If there are conflicts on merge, it means you were also committing code to the `stable` branch.  If you absolutely don't want the `stable` branch, why not just use a clone and replace the older repository when it is no longer required.

Comment: well i dont need stable's code, but i would like to keep the history. so how can i force my changes from dev to stable and merge them?